# How to Create Apple Developer Account in Afghanistan

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I wanna start developing a mobile application for android, iOS and windows platforms (I am using ionic framework), the problem that I am facing is that **I am based on Afghanistan country** so **how to create an apple developer account**, since the application is for a business so **what type of account** do I need?, .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You need a developer account, Apple developer accounts are of two types.

1. Enrolling as an Individual
2. Enrolling as an Organization

While enrolling as an individual or organization you need to create an Apple ID and turn on two-factor-authentication in your mobile device. However, if you want to register as an organization you need the following

- A D-U-N-S® Number
- Legal Entity Status
- Legal Binding Authority
- A Website

In either case, if you want to register from Afghanistan or for Afghanistan, do not bind your Apple ID to Itunes & App Store or else you have to choose a location service that Afghanistan is not on that list.

--- If you choose a location other than Afghanistan then it will change your Apple ID location and also it will affect payment and shipping information as well. In this case, you will have zero chance to participate in Apple developer programs for Afghanistan.

NOTE: **Do not bind your Apple ID to Itunes and App store, rest is the normal process and you can follow the enrollment process from this link ( https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/ )**

Comment: Hi Mr. Mohammad Naim,
I wanted to know is it possible to create a play store developer account from Afghanistan? If yes, how? Thank you Mr. Naim for your time.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189301/8740349

Comment: **See also:** StackOverflow.com/[Sharing paid-developer-account options?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189301/8740349)

Comment: @AshrafBawer, sorry for a very delayed response, however it is much easier to have a registered play store developer account from Afghanistan and process is pretty similar to any other country. (It is not complicated like Apple developer account).